# How can i seperate some characters from one big string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a big string and I put its characters into a list called `chars`. I want to separate some specific characters from it.

for example:

```
chars = ["ü","ç","ö","a","ş","ğ","ı","d"]
chars2 = []
```

Just a simple python 3.7 with pycharm on my windows

```
    for i in chars:
        if i != "ü" or "ğ" or "ç" or "ö" or "ş" or "ı":
            chars2.append(i)
    print(chars2)
```

Expected result: `['a','d']`

Result: `['ü','ç','ö','a','ş','ğ','ı','d']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly change it as follows for your code to work

```py
    for i in chars:
        if i != "ü" and i!= "ğ" and i!="ç" and i!= "ö" and i!="ş" and i!="ı":
            chars2.append(i)
    print(chars2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For better maintainability you could put the chars you want to filter into a separate list, and do this:

```
chars = ["ü","ç","ö","a","ş","ğ","ı","d"]
filter = ["ü","ç","ö","ş","ğ","ı"]

chars2 = [c for c in chars if c not in filter]
```

Comment: To add to that, there's not reason to explode strings into lists of their characters as python strings are iterables of their characters already. `[c for c in input_str if c not in filter_str]` will work if `input_str` and `filter_str` are strings too.